# Fix toilet flange in concrete or leave it?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, flange

Getting ready to do a levelling/flattening pour on bathroom floor but need to decide what to do with the flange first as it is was put in too low originally. The floor around the flange shouldn't be raised up by the pour, as it the high spot, but if I should fix the flange I want to do it prior to leveling.

Obviously this can (and has) worked with 1/2"-3/4" flooring, via things like flange extenders and Fernco wax-free seal, but it is not obviously not desirable or correct to have not be flush with the finished floor (or on top of it). It appears to be the external fit to the 3" pipe which seems to make removal difficult from what I've been able to look up.  Extra difficult given it is embedded in concrete and risky if I were to damage the pipe it is connected to.

Looking for suggestions as to whether to leave it as is or not, and if not, how best to approach the difficulty of removing it to add a new one (that can go up an inch).

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A toilet flange which is to high is far worse than a toilet flange which is to low. There needs to be a gap between to make room for flexible material to create a seal in between. When you are on the toilet wiping, you shake the toilet while the floor stays still.

Some toilets hate a flange on top of the finished floor and will leak because of it. Some older toilets want the flange to be low. In short, it is generally assumed that the flange will be attached to the subfloor and a floor will exist which raises the area around the flange. If this is not your case, then make sure that the toilet you buy allows the flange to be on top of the floor. Most new toilets allow it.

There are a million ways to fill a gap between the toilet and its flange, but lifting the pipe which is in the concrete is not one of them. It is much easier to stack wax rings.

Although I would replace the bolts, there is nothing wrong with the toilet flange that already exists. If something does go wrong with the flange in the future, then a new flange can be added atop the old one and life goes onward.

What you have is good. Leave it be.